# Java/Android: How to display series of imageViews without cutting off edge views?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I am trying to display a series of 4 avatars in a reusable layout. My layout `test_layout.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am going to reuse this layout in multiple places (sometimes multiple times on the same screen) so it needs to be its own layout incorporated via `include` tag (or maybe `merge`).

When the frame is too wide/short, this layout looks great and exactly as I intended, with the avatars in 'packed' formation:
[image: Four avatars side by side in 'packed' formation with no extra whitespace between, just extra whitespace on the side]

However when the frame is too narrow/tall, the layout starts cutting off the images on the outside: [image: Four avatars side by side, but the frame is not wide enough to accommodate all of them at full height so instead it cuts off parts of the images on the side]

How do I get this so that instead of cutting off the sides of the images, it instead resizes them so they all fit horizontally and adds whitespace to the top and bottom? I am open to any type of layout, not just `constraintlayout`. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `ScrollView`?

Comment: @Mustansir, I am not looking for it to be scrollable, I'd like all four images displayed at all times

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is probably setup the LayoutParams for those four ImageView programmatically:

```
int totalWidth = yourConstraintLayout.getWidth();
yourImageView1.setLayoutParams(new  ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(totalWidth / 4, totalWidth / 4));

// And the same thing for the rest of your imageViews, or just use a for loop
```

This would just always set the width of the pictures to be one-fourth of their parent(the ConstraintLayout.) I think this is what you're asking? Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: I'm using placeholder images in the screenshots but in reality the images are of varying widths and will change throughout the app lifetime, so unfortunately this approach won't work. I need it to dynamically adjust to whatever size the images are

Answer (score 0):

set your test_layout.xml height `wrap_content` and width `match_constraints`

and then if you use include to add to another layout you need set the height `wrap_content` to keep the orginal size

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this makes the whole container disappear since all of the individual image heights are 0 (necessary for utilizing ConstraintLayout's `match_constraints` behavior), did I misunderstand?

Comment: @NicoleGerber sorry my miss, check the edited answer, I try to change the width as `match_constraints` and height to `wrap_content` for the fixed width to any screen size

Comment: ah ok, another poster suggested this but the issue is that this fixed the problem for when the container is too narrow/tall, but now the avatars don't respect the packed chain style when the container is too wide, and instead they are spread out. I also tried with both dimensions as wrap_content but this still cut off the images on the outside when the container was too narrow

Answer (score 0):

Set all the widths to match constraint and all heights to wrap content

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

Comment: this fixed the problem for when the container is too narrow/tall, but now the avatars don't respect the `packed` chain style when the container is too wide, and instead they are spread out. I also tried with both dimensions as `wrap_content` but this still cut off the images on the outside when the container was too narrow

Answer (score 0):

I think doing it programmatically as @Zuo Wang says, its the best option. But if you don't want to do it that way and still do it by XML. Here you have maybe a approach. Setting a maxHeight, and yet that would not fit in all device screens.

**Here you hace a preview by Height of 250dp**

[image]

**And here you have it by height of 50dp**

[image]

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: it's weird, this introduces whitespace at the top and bottom when the container is too narrow (which is good), but it still cuts off parts of the images on the side at the same time. I'm not sure why both of these things are allowed to happen simultaneously